# Generating a comma separated file with newline for a bulk insert produces unexpected output

Tags: c#, vb.net, csv, bulkinsert

I need for a bulk insert into `SQL-Server` a Comma-Separated File. My data (survey data where each person has a row to store the answers ending with a `vblf`) are comming from a `Server-Send-Event` and I stream it into a textfile. I do the following transfomation to the data to secure the format:

```
Dim allText As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\_downloaded Data\new.csv")
        allText = allText.Replace("data:[", String.Empty)
        allText = allText.Replace(vbLf, String.Empty)
        allText = allText.Replace("]", Environment.NewLine)
    Using output As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\_downloaded Data\new.csv")
        output.WriteLine(allText)
    End Using
```

Since the data are in the format `data:[1,asdf,3,test@gmail.de]` I delete the `data:[` then I delete all `vbLF`'s since I do not know if some are on the wrong place, I have text in there as well and at the very end I replace `]` with a `NewLine` since in my insert code:

```
BULK INSERT insert_Table_1 FROM 'C:\_downloaded Data\new.csv'
With (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n')
```

I use as `ROWTERMINATOR \r\n`. The data to import look fine within `csv`

[image]

But when I insert them into SQL-Server (where `\n` and `0x0a` are not working and giving me an `Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file. error`) the data within the table look like this

[image]

and I have no idea why. Is there any mistake in the .net code (c# solutions are welcome as well). I cannot find some in the import code.

Comment: Did you try to take a look at the file with an advanced editor like Notepad++ to see all the chars? Are you sure Environment.NewLine is \r\n?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the last NewLine. The way you did it will create en empty line at the end.

Comment: I have tried Notepad but could not see anything. Yet I have converted it to HEX (even though this is not really my element) and get this: 332C312C320D0A332C322C320D0A352C312C32. Everything ok. I now created a simple testfile not coming from the stream I just did a csv file and now I get the same output. Looks like this is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: The csv file has to have the same name as the table. Now it is working.